# SwiftUI DatePicker triggers touch events when dismissed

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

I have a compact DatePicker that displays a calendar when opened with a rather standard declaration:

```
    DatePicker(
        self.name,
        selection: self.$date,
        displayedComponents: self.components
    ).labelsHidden()
```

After selecting a date, I want to tap outside the calendar to dismiss and validate my date. The problem is the tap triggers touch events whereever I tapped. How to have the DatePicker calendar behaving as a real modal popover?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had the similar idea and could only solve it by (and you probably thought of that already) putting an invisible view behind it and register the tap gesture.

Comment: Yeah it's just that I expect and hope SwiftUI has elegant solutions to those weird default behavior that I'm tired of fixing with ugly workarounds...

Comment: What's your code for this because I've trouble making it work?

Comment: I'm at work now but this is close to the approach to what we did (hope it helps): https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-dismiss-custom-modal

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. Tested on Xcode 14, iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gesture recognizer on the Datepicker to bind the touch action to the picker